# Ejabberd installation strange issue

Tags: erlang, debian, xmpp, ejabberd

OS: Debian 8.1 X64

trying to install eJabberd Community server [based on this tutorial](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-with-binary-installer)

At the end of installation, it pops error message

```
Error: Error running Post Install Script.
The installation may have not completed correctly
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `/bin/sh` is Dash on your system (apparently [the default since Debian Squeeze](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh)).  However, the `postinstall.sh` script inside the package uses [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), which while widely supported in various shells is not required by the POSIX standard, and thus Dash is not in error by not supporting it.  The `postinstall.sh` script should either specify `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh` in its first line, or abstain from using Bash-specific features.

You should be able to get a functioning ejabberd install by explicitly running the postinstall script with Bash:

```
sudo bash /opt/ejabberd-15.07/bin/postinstall.sh
```

Comment: Right, it wanted to create a user, and expected the details to be passed as command line arguments to the postinstall script. You can create a user manually with `ejabberdctl register`; the server itself should be fine.

Comment: Not sure, I haven't installed a fresh ejabberd on Debian for quite some time. Shameless plug: you may want to try MongooseIM, my employer's fork of ejabberd: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-mongooseim